# CSS representation between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

The following CSS3 animated button:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/meetaaronsilber/RN63Y/`
```

works when loaded in Chrome but not in Firefox. Is there any point in trying to make it work or should I move on?

Comment: What is the meaning of life?

Comment: everywhere you see -webkit- add the same line but where -webkit- is put -moz-

Comment: I did this already with no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: ok one sec, im going to re-edit my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun in what you do, TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere you see '-webkit-' add the same line but where '-webkit-' is insert '-moz-'. Here is a small snippet of your code, you have a lot to change so i wasn't going to do the whole thing.

**Edit:** Try all of them including the basic. see if that works.

```css
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
  
     -moz-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
     -o-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
    -ms-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
     box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */
    
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, it won't work. You can test it in the editor window in the link I provided. The addition of -moz- adds some minimal action to the button but there is no shadow and no proper movement, compared to Chrome attitude.

Comment: I dont have Moz on my workstation atm, but ur telling me this doesnt work on moz: [Updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RN63Y/1902/)

Comment: newwer version: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RN63Y/1905/)

Comment: Actually it worked by calling just the plain property (i.e. box-shadow) and not the -moz- transition. Thank you very much for the time.

Comment: no problem, cool button btw.

Comment: "Press Me" wont highlight in this code when u click it a million times like I do: [http://jsfiddle.net/RN63Y/1907/](http://jsfiddle.net/RN63Y/1907/). I just added `-webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    -o-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;` to `.button` .